# How to add existing add name in system out println

Tags: java

Please I need help with Java code. the method `addVapen` (add weapon) is supposed to add weapons name but when the name is already been added it would say "this weapon is already added with the name: [add weapon name]".
Everything works fine, it just wont show  the name that I just added in the `system.out.println()`!

```
    public void addVapen (SuperVapen enVapen)
    {
        if (!vapen.contains(enVapen)){
            vapen.add(enVapen);
            System.out.println("new weapon is added to the superhero");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Superhero already have this weapon with the name:" [HERE I WANT TO BE THE NAME I AM TRYING TO ADD]);
        }
    }
```

code for the other class

```
public class SuperVapen
{

    private String superVapenNamn;

    public SuperVapen(String superVapenNamn)
    {
        this.superVapenNamn = superVapenNamn;
    }

    public String getSuperVapenNamn()
    {
        return superVapenNamn;
    }

}
```

Comment: SO isn't a website to do your homework. Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What is your question here? What have you tried?

Comment: I think: `System.out.println("Superhero already have this weapon with the name: " + enVapen.getSuperVapenNamn());`. The `+` operator can be used for string concatenation.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks it works! u r the best love u :*)

Comment: @SébastienTemprado u taking this way too serious :) in Swedish we say "ta det lugnt" :)

Comment: Själv tack. :-)

Comment: @OleV.V. Tack :p